# Why is in Rust the expression in Option.and evaluated, if option is None?

Tags: rust, option-type, panic, unwrap

I don't understand, why Option.and() is evaluated, if option is None. The documentation says ....

*Returns None if the option is None, otherwise it returns optb (the argument of and()).*

So I would expect, that and() is only (and only then) taken into account, if option is not None. But obviously this is not the case. Let's look the following code ....

```
let n: Option<i32> = None;
let m = n.and(Some(n.unwrap()));
```

I know this is a stupid sample, but it's just to make hopefully my point clearer.

- So n is None
- Therefore I would expect, that in the second line just None is assigned to m.
- But when running the code I get a panic, because it's tried to unwrap n which is None. Of course this panics, but why is n.unwrap() executed, if n is None? I would have assumed, that the expression of and() is only evaluated, if the option is not None, which is obviously not the case. What have I missed?

Comment: [Opened a PR to copy the warning from `or()` about the eager evaluation](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/100921).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because `and()` is a normal function, and when you call a function first Rust evaluates its arguments.

What you want is [`and_then()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.and_then):

```rust
let m = n.and_then(|_| Some(n.unwrap()));
```

It takes a closure to be able to avoid evaluating the argument.

Comment: I think you need `|_| Some(n.unwrap())` as the closure because it takes the value from the option.

Comment: `and_then` is also a "normal function." This is not the difference. The difference is that `and` takes the replacement value directly, while `and_then` takes a closure that produces it.

Comment: @cdhowie Yes, this is why I said it takes a closure.

Comment: Right, I think the phrase "because `and()` is a normal function" is what threw me. It sounded at first read like this is intended to contrast `and_then()`, the implication being that it's _not_ a "normal function" but I think what you're actually saying here is simply that there's nothing special about `and()`.

Comment: @cdhowie this could also be in contrast with the (still experimental I think) proposal of having "macro methods" which could allow something like `n.and!{...}` which would only compute the value if it was required.

Comment: @BlackBeans This is called "postfix macros" and not implemented, not even accepted yet. Even if it would work, we may want typed macros for that.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman although it's not accepted yet, it's actually already implemented! There is [a crate](https://docs.rs/postfix-macros/0.1.0/postfix_macros/) that does it.

Comment: @BlackBeans Yeah, this can be said about a lot of features, but it is not implemented as a language feature. Besides, using macros like that is not ergonomic.